# Textures are inside the model

Tags: import, .fbx

I've imported a FBX model (made by someone else in Blender), but the textures are inside the model. Recalculating your and reuploading the textures didn't help.

[image: outside]

[image: inside]

UPD: the model itself https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Btqvb60qj4HtmpKEWG0E-dG--hYd7dR6

Comment: Please share your file so we can see what's going on with it. My first guess is that there's a Geometry node with the Facing attribute somewhere in your shader node tree.

Comment: May be the light source is inside of the object.

Comment: @PJM I've added the link

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Backface Culling in the material settings. It is the extra geometry for creating an outline blocking the view.

[image]

You can build a custom toon shader. Here is one:

[image]

This is for EEVEE only.

[image]

If you want you can watch some tutorials on Non-PBR shading. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3zHGD8V2IY or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCF29s2FRsQ